# Docker + Nginx + ngx_http_image_filter_module

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

Help me please in configuring `Nginx` with the `ngx_http_image_filter_module` module for `Docker`.

I want to create image thumbnails with Nginx. I know that `ngx_http_image_filter_module` is needed for this. If I take a look at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/8921999083def7ba43a06fabd5f80e4406651353/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile) for [Nginx standard container](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) I can see that it is already built with `nginx-module-image-filter` (I believe it is what I need). But when I try to use `image_filter resize 100 100` in Nginx config Docker doesn't start this container and throws an error:

> nginx_1       | 2016/11/13 13:28:28 [emerg] 1#1: unknown directive "image_filter" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:34
>
> nginx_1       | nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "image_filter" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:34

I have already tried building container with my own Dockerfile, but nothing changed. **I used this Dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
                        nginx-module-image-filter
```

**My host config** (located under /etc/nginx/conf.d/)

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location /images/originals/ {
    alias /site/storage/app/public/images/originals/;
    image_filter resize 100 100;
  }
}
```

## Update

**Nginx config (standard)**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Btw, if I bash into nginx container and run `nginx -V` I get the following:

> root@8abdbeab3e2e:/etc/nginx/conf.d# nginx -V
>
> nginx version: nginx/1.11.5
>
> built by gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
>
> built with OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
>
> TLS SNI support enabled
>
> configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed'

As we can see there's no Image filter module here.

## Update 2

**apt-get install nginx-extras-dbg**

```
root@e124bcecfddc:/# apt-get install nginx-extras-dbg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  init-system-helpers libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common nginx-common nginx-extras
Suggested packages:
  fcgiwrap nginx-doc ssl-cert
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  init-system-helpers libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common nginx-common nginx-extras nginx-extras-dbg
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 5920 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7880 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main nginx-common all 1.6.2-5+deb8u4 [88.1 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main nginx-extras amd64 1.6.2-5+deb8u4 [595 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main nginx-extras-dbg amd64 1.6.2-5+deb8u4 [4982 kB]
Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libluajit-5.1-common all 2.0.3+dfsg-3 [36.6 kB]
Get:5 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libluajit-5.1-2 amd64 2.0.3+dfsg-3 [204 kB]
Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main init-system-helpers all 1.22 [14.0 kB]
Fetched 5920 kB in 6s (967 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package libluajit-5.1-common.
(Reading database ... 9747 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libluajit-5.1-common_2.0.3+dfsg-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libluajit-5.1-common (2.0.3+dfsg-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libluajit-5.1-2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libluajit-5.1-2_2.0.3+dfsg-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libluajit-5.1-2:amd64 (2.0.3+dfsg-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package init-system-helpers.
Preparing to unpack .../init-system-helpers_1.22_all.deb ...
Unpacking init-system-helpers (1.22) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-common.
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.6.2-5+deb8u4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/nginx/scgi_params', which is also in package nginx 1.11.5-1~jessie
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-extras.
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-extras_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-extras (1.6.2-5+deb8u4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-extras_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/nginx', which is also in package nginx 1.11.5-1~jessie
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-extras-dbg.
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-extras-dbg_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-extras-dbg (1.6.2-5+deb8u4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-extras_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**apt-get install libgd-dev**

```
root@e124bcecfddc:/# apt-get install libgd-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd-dev : Depends: libgd3 (= 2.1.0-5+deb8u7) but 2.1.0-5+deb8u6 is to be installed
             Depends: libpng-dev
             Depends: libz-dev
             Depends: libjpeg-dev
             Depends: libfreetype6-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libxpm-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libx11-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libfontconfig-dev
             Depends: libvpx-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libtiff-dev
 nginx-extras-dbg : Depends: nginx-extras (= 1.6.2-5+deb8u4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**apt-get -f install**

```
root@e124bcecfddc:/# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nginx-common nginx-extras
Suggested packages:
  fcgiwrap nginx-doc ssl-cert
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nginx-common nginx-extras
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 683 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1812 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main nginx-common all 1.6.2-5+deb8u4 [88.1 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main nginx-extras amd64 1.6.2-5+deb8u4 [595 kB]
Fetched 683 kB in 0s (1444 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
(Reading database ... 9786 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.6.2-5+deb8u4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/nginx/scgi_params', which is also in package nginx 1.11.5-1~jessie
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-extras_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-extras (1.6.2-5+deb8u4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-extras_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/nginx', which is also in package nginx 1.11.5-1~jessie
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-extras_1.6.2-5+deb8u4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

## Update 3

I've cleaned up everything, deleted all images and containers and start from scratch.

I use this docker-compose file for my nginx container:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx
    build:
      context: ./env/nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./env/nginx/abmotors.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/abmotors.conf:ro
```

This is the Dockerfile located at ./env/nginx (for building nginx container)

```
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
                        libgd-dev \
                        nginx-module-image-filter
```

Everything builds up, but when I ran and bash into nginx container and run `nginx -V` it gives me following:

```
root@7087db72bdb1:/# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.11.6
built by gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed'
```

Still no information about libgd nor image-filter module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your entire nginx.conf? When I try to add your server directive to the nginx.conf I get the following error - `nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:34`

Comment: @YaronIdan very sorry for my wrong explanation. That was not the nginx.conf content, but the content of my host config. I've updated the post.
Also I've added an output of `nginx -V` command.

Comment: @YaronIdan I can show you my `docker-compose.yml` if it makes sense.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nginx introduced dynamic modules in 1.9.11 and "image-filter" is just one of the dynamic modules right now.

Nginx standard Docker image already provides it:

```
$ docker run -it --rm nginx:mainline ls -l /etc/nginx/modules/ | grep image
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23536 Oct 11 15:54 ngx_http_image_filter_module-debug.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23536 Oct 11 15:54 ngx_http_image_filter_module.so
```

But the module is not loaded by the default Nginx root configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, because it is considered "optional". What you need to do is to put the following line into that file:

```
load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;
```

**at the top level!** That is where `daemon`, `user`, `http` are defined.

Comment: Alexander, there seems to be no errors now. I'll make some research and tests and leave a feedback. Thanks for now ;)

Comment: Alexander, it worked like a charm! I'm so happy now, thank you very much for this tip!

Comment: I may award my bounty in 21 hours, so we have to wait for it.

Comment: @VictorRudkov Glad to hear you are happy

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to install `libdg` module most likely. Refer to the documenation [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html)

Try installing it with `sudo apt-get install nginx-extras-dbg` and recompile.

Comment: I have tried all of this and even more: apt-get -f install. But looks like something is going wrong. I have updated my post with the results, take a look please.

Comment: I cleaned up everything – deleted all images and containers. In a couple of minutes I'll start from scratch and post here the results.

Comment: @msj I'm also looking into it

Comment: I've updated the post with a little more info. See Update 3 pls